# How to set live/video wallpaper in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, wallpaper, live-wallpaper

I want to set video.mp4 as a live wallpaper in flutter.
I used async_live_wallpaper package but its open another app/activity for setting live wallpaper please provide me a another solution to set live wallpaper without openning third party app or activity.

I want to set live wallpaper without using third party app or activity.